# Using friend to access private variable in templated classes

Tags: c++, templates

I get the following error from the program below:

use of undeclared identifier 'value'

Why? And, how do I fix it using friend classes?

Thanks in advance.

```
template <typename T>
class F2 : public F1<T>
{
public:
  F2(T o) : F1<T>(o) {}

  void fun() {
    std::cout << value << std::endl;
  }
};

template <typename T>
class F1
{
public:
    template <typename U>
    friend class F2;

    F1(T o) : value(o) {}

protected:
  T value;
};

int main()
{
    F2<int> f(3);
}
```

Comment: Is this your actual code?  `F2` derives from `F1` which is **after** it in your code sample.

Comment: Yes, otherwise it complains about the friend not being an elaborated type.

Comment: @NiallC: Presumably there's a forward declaration above.  Not having the body until after use is fine with templates, as long as the body is available at the point the template gets instantiated (naming the type `F2<int>` inside `main()`)

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard prescribes that all names that are not dependent on template parameters are bound when parsing a template function, rather than when it is instantiated, which is otherwise when the reference to the inherited `value` could be detected.

The quick workaround is to use `this->value`; because `this` is dependent on the template parameter it is bound when the function is instantiated and the reference to the inherited `value` is therefore permitted.

Comment: I have noticed examples where I thought there were extraneous uses of  "this". I now know why they were there. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems here:

1) `F2` isn't templated, so everywhere you're using `T` in `F2` is incorrect

2) `F1` (the base class) is defined after `F2`, move `F2` to below `F1`

3) A base class is friending it's derived class. It shouldn't know about its derived class.

Is this your *actual* code? If so is the error you wrote your *actual* error? I would expect numerous errors for an array of reasons.

Comment: I hadn't noticed, but I missed the first line which is  template <typename T>